# Zones missing after running zonal statistics in ArcGIS Spatial Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics, missing-data

I have a problem using zonal statistics in ArcGIS.

My raster contains values/data with 30m cells.

I had several vector layers, containing administrative subdivisions of Belgium. I have converted the vector layers to raster data with the Polygon to Raster tool. I used the cell center assignment and used the same cell-size than that of my value raster data.

Each time I use zonal statistics, 2 zones are missing. I don't understand why ?

It's not a size problem as these are not necessary the smallest zones.

I tried the same procedure using another raster data sets for defining the zones, and the same occurs at a different location.

[image]

Comment: Which Statistics type did you use? Is your "Input value raster" area contains the missing zones?

Comment: The missing zones are not missing in the Input Data. I tried with mean and variance.

Comment: With the "Ignore NoData in calculation" option unchecked?

Comment: Lame answer but may help Check wether the zone is not white out due to Black white symbology try to use plain symbology only black and check output data coverage.

Comment: No this is not the case. I checked off course !

Comment: Have you tried using the Vector Layers as they are to run the Zonal Stats, rather than converting them to Raster and then running the tool?

Comment: @KeaganAllan yes, it didn't solve the problem

Comment: Ok, some additional tests. Check the projection between the input layers. Also try running the "Check" and "Repair" Geometry tools with the vector layers before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

The only time I have had a similar issue, it was because my Processing Extents were out of wack. Here is what I did: Go to Environment Settings > Processing Extent > Extent: Union of Inputs. I'm not sure if this is the issue, but hope it helps.